# IndexError: tuple index out of range in tf.Model.fit()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to train my first network in tensorflow and get the 'IndexError: tuple index out of range'. Here is the source code:

```
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.Input(shape=(104,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(92, activation="relu", name="end_game_in"))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="end_game_h1"))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name="end_game_h2"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu", name="end_game_out"))
model.summary()

train_dataset , test_dataset, val_dataset = load_data()

model.compile( optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),  # Optimizer
    # Loss function to minimize
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    # List of metrics to monitor
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],)

print("Fit model on training data")
x_train =[]
y_train = []
count = 0
for it in train_dataset :
    x , y = it
    x_train.append(x.astype("float32"))
    y_train.append(y.astype("float32"))
    count += 1
    if count % 5000 == 0:
        print("Train: ", count)

x_val =[]
y_val = []
count = 0
for it in val_dataset :
    x , y = it
    x_val.append(x.astype("float32"))
    y_val.append(y.astype("float32"))
    count += 1
    if count % 5000 == 0:
        print("Val: ", count)

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=10,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)

history.history
```

An here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\My Drive\Personal\Spider\Datasets\ModelEGame.py", line 90, in <module>
    history = model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\jordi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\jordi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 908, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

length of `x_train` is 35,000 of `shape=(104,)` length of `y_train` is 35,000 of `shape=()`
length of `x_val` is 5,000 of `shape=(104,)` length of `y_val` is 5,000 of `shape=()`

Given other questions here, I tried `pip3 install tf-nightly`, but the error continues.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np  
x_train = np.array(x_train)
```